# What's a word for someone who has completed an exercise?

Tags: word-choice

I want to refer to people who have completed a short written exercise. "Graduate" would be one way, but that seems a little over the top. "Completer" would be another, but that's ambiguous as a completer could be something that helps you to complete. Any ideas?

Comment: A *completer* is not necessarily one who has completed, it could be someone tasked with completing as well. One way of expressing the idea is perhaps to use the phrase *the completed*: "The completed must remain in their seats and not leave the room."

Comment: Nice idea Kris. I don't think it would work in this context though as in a sentence you get "exercise completed" which sounds like a completed exercises.

Comment: You don't need the *exercise* part as an adverb there. Even otherwise, those who passed the exam may call themselves *(some-exam) passed* and those who completed may call themselves *(some-exam) completed*.

Comment: I should have mentioned, this will form part of an API, I want to be able to say exercise.first.graduates or similar.

Comment: "those who completed" or "have completed"

Comment: I think basic language constructs allow you to get the idea across without the need for a single word, any one if which in this context will sound infelicitous. You canbusr a single word, but it'll sound weird.

Comment: Those who have completed the exercise.

Answer (score 5):

A nice unambiguous term is *those who have completed the test.*

However, ***finisher*** is often used for those who have crossed the finish line in a race, and may work in your case.

> **finisher** *noun*
>   **1** a person or thing that finishes something, in particular:
>      • a person who reaches the end of a race or other competition:
>           *all finishers will receive a commemorative medal*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finisher)

Comment: I like that a lot. Congratulations to all the Exercise Finishers...